# PHP MWS Samples set up, returning a blank screen.

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I've successfully pulled reports with my authentication in scratchpad, set up the samples given by amazon "amazon-mws-v20090101-php-2015-06-18.*V316922310*" configured ".config.inc.php" and picked the correct endpoint within the given samples such as "GetReportListSample.php"  if I have an error or Mock() it will show feedback. But when I try to run it all that comes back is a blank page within my browser. Am i doing something wrong or is there another way to display the data received from this request?

Thanks.

Comment: The information should not be shown in the browser unless you print it.

Comment: In the client.php file, there is this like `curl_setopt(SSL_VERIFYHOST,true)` make it false.